# Add hour and min to date?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have date comes from request for example `20-08-2021` I need to put the hour & min with it and be something like that `2021-20-08 14:18:12` to store in database

I tried this but it stores in DB like date of now!

```
$data['expires_at'] = $request->expires_at . '-' . now()->format('h:m');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the date to Carbon with createFromFormat so that it sets the time, then you can use the formatter functions

```
$data['expires_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->expires_at)->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: "The separation symbol could not be foundTrailing data" I go this error

Comment: Hmm, sounds like not every date is the `d-m-Y` format as shown in your original date. Add `Log::info($request->expires_at);` before that line and try again to see exactly what format it's in. Parse would be a better option to guess the date format without specifying it, but it sets the time to midnight if the time isn't specified.